# Jquery: how to detect when some element is added to dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want something like:

```
$('.pac-container').whenAddToDom(function(){
    console.log('element with class pac-container added to DOM');
    //I want to use this added element $(this).doSomethingWithThis();
});
```

Comment: Check this question. It may helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: Or this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: ***Mutation Observers*** is what you are looking for.

Comment: you can listen to elements that are being appended `.bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solution to my problem:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(element){
    if($(this).hasClass('pac-container')){
        console.log(element.target);
    }

});
```

Comment: This solution is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events). Use MutationObserver instead if possible (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: @PhilippePerret that doesn't help at all

Comment: Your notice is useless, @f7n. Could you explain?

Answer (score 4):

I would wrap the elements that will be appended in a container and do something like this:

```
$("html").bind("DOMNodeInserted",function(){
    console.log('element with class '+$("#container > *").attr('class') +' added to DOM');
});
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PgAJT/295/